# Why won't my changes in git go through?

Tags: git

All I wanted to do was to add all files.

Now I got directories that are just icons and I never saw something like that before.

I just wanted to add all files. I did

```
git add *
git commit -m "added"
git push
```

And now I got this incomprehensible mess.

[image]

How can you explain this state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those gray folders are **[gitlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)).
They represent **nested git repos**: the parent repo only records their SHA1 (that you see beside the grey icons)

You need to decide if you want to:

- record them properly as **[submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**
- ignore them completely
- add their content in your repo (removing their inner `.git` folder)

Note: don't use `git add *`: the `*` is expanded by the shell.
Use `git add .`

Comment: I want to create a new clean repo after making important changes from another repo. I want to release the connections to the old repo and start this repo as new.

Comment: @DjDac yes, but do you need the history of all those nested git repos? If not, remove any `.git` directory, do a `git init .` and try again your `git add .`

Comment: I don't need the history. I made so large changes that it should be like a new start.

Comment: Then removing any `.git` folder you can find, doing a new `git init .`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "first commit"` and `git push --force -u origin master` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below on cmd, cli, shell or git bash.

1. git status
2. git add -A
3. git commit -m "[your commit message]"
4. git push origin {your-branch}

example:

1. git status [enter]
2. git add -A [enter]
3. git commit -m "new commit" [enter]
4. git push origin master [enter]

Don't use "git add .", because it will overwrite all of your code.