# How do I delete a submodule on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, terminal

I accidentally created a submodule on GitHub after forcing a commit. For some reason, I can't wipe my repository and start over so I need some way to delete the submodule so I can recommit. Is there any way I can delete the submodule through my terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it actually is a submodule, meaning your GitHub repo also have a `.gitmodules` files recording the associated path of that submodule, see [my answer here](http://1.%20git%20submodule%20deinit%20-f%20--%20a/submodule%20%20%20%20%202.%20rm%20-rf%20.git/modules/a/submodule%203.%20git%20rm%20-f%20a/submodule):

```
1. git submodule deinit -f -- a/submodule    
2. rm -rf .git/modules/a/submodule
3. git rm -f a/submodule
```

Then commit and push.

But if it is a simple **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, displayed as a grayed folder on GitHub, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43108649/6309), then just remove it locally and push:

```
git rm -f a/submodule
git commit -m "remove submodule gitlink"
git push
```